# AC polarity detection circuitry

Tags: ac, polarity

The three wires in a marinr 120 VAC shore-power circuit are normally black for power, white for neutral, and green for ground.

I’m searching for a circuit that will power an idiot-light in order to determine if my boat is properly connected to shore power.

I want my black wire connected to the dock’s black wire, and so on up the circuit.

The peril of having mixed wires in a marine setting apparently is a charge electrifying/ energizing the sea around the vessel.

Comment: What is the normal configuration for earth and neutral for boat situations?

Comment: These can be bought from hardware stores in the form of test plugs. Why not use those?

Comment: I would guess you probably just want to see if there is any big voltage difference between neutral and ground. If there is one = neutral is actually hot (and hot is actually neutral)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have an accessible outlet for hotel power, I would go down to the hardware store and get a line fault detector.  It will let you know if everything is correctly connected or what is not connected correctly.  It is also safer than trying to roll your own both from a manufacturing standpoint (built to relevant safety standards) and an operational standpoint (circuit is known to correctly indicate the presence of a fault).

[image: Kretech AC Line Fault Detector]

Image from Kretech